# I am trying to make a very basic calculator that can work with one input, but I am struglling a little

Tags: java, python

So I have 2 different code for a calculator, one is a little to advanced, while the other is unfinished. I am trying to get help to either make my finished one a little basic because I don't know what approach to take to bring it a notch down or to help me finish my other code.

So I have tried to make the calculator work very basically but it had 3 different input and I need to work it out with only one input.

The finished product (Kind of advanced one)

The unfinished product

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: first version is good and simple. Only I would'n write all in `print(...)`  because it make code less readable.

Comment: as @furas says, by the time you get your second one working, it wouldn't be more complex than the first one.  I would suggest that you compute a `result` variable in each `if`, like `result = int(exp[0]) - int(exp[1])`.  Then print the answer at the bottom with just one `print` statement.  Also, you don't need the outer `int` cast, because your expressions are already producing `int`s.

Comment: i don't know what you want to do in second version but it starts looking very similar to first version. If you need something different (you need challenge) then built parser using [PLY - Python Lex Yacc](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) or [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this would be considered basic or not, but consider the eval() function. Basically it translates the input to python code and runs it, and since the user input is likely to be the same as the python code, you can just run the input.

```
expr = input("In: ")
print(eval(expr))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your going to get much less complex than the first version.

The only adjustment I could suggest is if you are only dealing with calculations that have a single mathematical operator you could use elif statements so you don't bother checking once you've found the correct one. Similar to how you've started off your second version.

```
user_input = input("In:")

    if '+' in user_input:
        exp = user_input.split('+')
        print("The result is: {0}".format(int(int(exp[0]) + int(exp[1]))))
    elif '-' in user_input:
        exp = user_input.split('-')
        print("The result is: {0}".format(int(int(exp[0]) - int(exp[1]))))
    elif '*' in user_input:
        exp = user_input.split('*')
        print("The result is: {0}".format(int(int(exp[0]) * int(exp[1]))))
    elif '/' in user_input:
        exp = user_input.split('/')
        print("The result is: {0}".format(int(int(exp[0]) / int(exp[1]))))
    elif '%' in user_input:
        exp = user_input.split('%')
        print("The result is: {0}".format(int(int(exp[0]) % int(exp[1]))))
```